# ArcPy: Distortion towards edges when exporting to TIFF

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff

I am writing a function to zoom to selection (based on a criteria) and Exporting it to TIFF.

The problem I am getting is that the when I load the exported TIFF image in Map, I am seeing distortion towards the edges (perfect near the center). Can someone help me with what am i doing wrong in this case. Attaching my code below:

```
def SelectDataZoomSelected(mpath, fpath, cond, opath):

# Import system modules
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mpath)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, fpath, df)[0]

# Use the SelectLayerByAttribute tool to select and zoom to the selection
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", cond)
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()

# Export the map to a TIFF
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,opath,df,640,480,96,'TRUE','24-BIT_TRUE_COLOR','NONE','TRUE')

# Clear the selection and refresh the active view
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

del mxd
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example picture of the result from your script?

Comment: @Martin posted the image. The roads in black are from TIFF and the red one's are from the shape file.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you export a section of your map manually?

Comment: @Martin Exporting a section of map manually gives perfect output (no distortion whatsoever). I have set same parameters (from manual export) in the code, but still getting distortion/skewness at edges.

Comment: Whats with the other exports - do they fail also? Try exporting to a PDF and see what that yields. Also: do you have Z values on the data? Looking at the image creates the impression that the data is 3D.

Comment: @til_b Z values are not there. the 3D effect is thanks to the distortion towards edged. Will try other exports and give feedback

Comment: Found Solution:
Changed the width and height from 640,480 to 820, 580.

Now, it is working perfect.